# Truly terrible streaming video (Netflix/Skype) quality over fast wi-fi

Tags: wireless-networking, video, skype, qos, netflix

I have Verizon FIOS with a 50/25 plan. Speedtest.net [reports](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3511067883) 21/28 over my 802.11n wi-fi connection. I can reliably pull over 4MB/s when [downloading Ubuntu](http://mirrors.advancedhosters.com/ubuntu-releases/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso).

But watching Netflix on my wi-fi enabled blu-ray player or holding Skype video calls is something of a nightmare. I've switched from Comcast to Verizon, swapped out the router, and tried two different laptops and three different operating systems (Windows Vista, 7, and 8.1).

I've turned off every Internet-enabled device I have to minimize congestion before watching Netflix on my blu-ray player. But I still get long sequences of blocky, jaggy content. Skype video calls are almost useless.

[image: sample Skype image] (No, that's not JPG compression...that's really how it looks.)

What in the world can I try to change?!

Comment: Simply stated if verizon connection to Netflix is conjusted there isn't anything you can do expect perhaps using a VPN got bad news for you comcast recently solved the netflix conjustuntion

Comment: You can try enabling QoS on the router, but it's unlikely to make a huge difference. Also, are you sure the other end of the link has bandwidth? Does your computer have the latest updates?

Comment: QOS won't help the problem isn't a intranet problem it's verizon over selling its services and filtering traffic and using contested Cdns